# Layout issue after adding a new array to table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I added a new array to an existing array, but the layout is broken.

The code to output the array is:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$comp_value_count; $i++) {
    $compPro = 'pro'.$i;
    $attrCount = $result[$compPro][11];//A count of how many options there are per product

    $compDescription  .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][2] . '</td>';
    $compModel        .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][3] . '</td>';
    $compWeight       .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][4] . '</td>';
    $compQuantity     .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][5] . '</td>';
    $compManufacturer .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][7] . '</td>';
    $compattr1      .= '<td>';
    for ($c=0; $c<=$attrCount; $c++){
        $compattr2      .=  $result[$compPro][8][$c] . $result[$compPro][9][$c] . "\n";
    }
    $compattr3      .= '</td>';

}


// create the display
echo '<tr class="rowEven"><th>'  . COMPARE_QUANTITY     . '</th>' . $compQuantity     . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowOdd"> <th>'  . COMPARE_MODEL        . '</th>' . $compModel        . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowEven"><th>'  . COMPARE_WEIGHT       . '</th>' . $compWeight       . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowOdd"> <th>'  . COMPARE_MANUFACTURER . '</th>' . $compManufacturer . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowEven"><th>'  . COMPARE_DESC         . '</th>' . $compDescription  . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowOdd"> <th>'  . COMPARE_OPTNAME      . '</th>' . $compattr1 . $compattr2 . $compattr3 . '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

}

A fiddle showing the layout this code generates is https://jsfiddle.net/uzmk61v7/2/

And another showing what I wanted it to look like is here https://jsfiddle.net/85wztu3z/1/

var_dump($result) output is below

```
array(2) { 
    ["pro1"]=> array(12) { 
    [0]=> string(191) "01 button stainless steel audio panel - surface" 
    [1]=> string(612) "01 button stainless steel audio panel - surface" 
    [2]=> string(144) "5101S - 1 button audio door entry phone intercom panel SRS surface mounted, vandal resistant 1 way traditional audio, BS316 stainless steel,..." 
    [3]=> string(5) "5101S" 
    [4]=> string(1) "0" 
    [5]=> string(1) "1" 
    [6]=> string(171) "£147.74 Inc VAT £123.12 Ex VAT" 
    [7]=> string(3) "SRS" 
    [8]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(12) "Call Buttons" 
        [1]=> string(8) "Mounting" 
        [2]=> string(6) "Finish" 
        [3]=> string(5) "Range" 
    } 
    [9]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(20) "1 call button"
        [1]=> string(20) "Surface mount"
        [2]=> string(35) "Stainless Steel VR (brushed)"
        [3]=> string(15) "SRS 5000" 
    } 
    [10]=> string(73) "remove"
    [11]=> string(1) "4" 
    } 

    ["pro2"]=> array(12) { 
    [0]=> string(200) "00 way VR brass video panel, size D"
    [1]=> string(576) "00 way VR brass video panel, size D"
    [2]=> string(148) "6600 - 0 button video door entry phone intercom panel Size D SRS vandal resistant 0 way traditional video, polished brass, engravable, door entry..." 
    [3]=> string(4) "6600" 
    [4]=> string(1) "0" 
    [5]=> string(1) "0" 
    [6]=> string(171) "£155.95 Inc VAT £129.96 Ex VAT" 
    [7]=> string(3) "SRS" 
    [8]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(8) "Mounting" 
        [1]=> string(6) "Finish" 
        [2]=> string(5) "Range" 
        [3]=> string(7) "Cabling" 
    }
    [9]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(18) "Flush mount"
        [1]=> string(21) "Polished brass" 
        [2]=> string(15) "SRS 4000" 
        [3]=> string(34) "SRS Video C + 6 + n cabling"
    } 
    [10]=> string(73) "remove" [11]=> string(1) "4" 
    } 
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: So open generated html and see what is wrong.

Comment: Could you show the `var_dump($result)` result?

Comment: @u_mulder I can see what's wrong, just can't figure out a fix
It's outputting 
<td><td>some content<br />more content<br /></td></td>
instead of 
<td>some content<br /></td><td>more content<br /></td>

Comment: @MarcosYoshihiroNakamine var_dump added to the bottom of the question

Comment: @StevePrice You are using `$result[$compPro][11]`, but your array has 8.
Could you put the array you used to generate the html?

Comment: @MarcosYoshihiroNakamine My apologies, I'd removed sections related to image, price etc. Of course, this changed all the array values! Updated to be a full, unedited dump

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more `<td></td>`

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$comp_value_count; $i++) {
    $compPro = 'pro'.$i;
    $attrCount = $result[$compPro][11];//A count of how many options there are per product
    $compDescription  .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][2] . '</td>';
    $compModel        .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][3] . '</td>';
    $compWeight       .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][4] . '</td>';
    $compQuantity     .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][5] . '</td>';
    $compManufacturer .= '<td>' . $result[$compPro][7] . '</td>';
    $compattr1      .= '<td>';
    for ($c=0; $c<=$attrCount; $c++){
        $compattr1      .=  $result[$compPro][8][$c] . "\n";
    }
    $compattr1      .= '</td>';
    $compattr2      .= '<td>';
    for ($c=0; $c<=$attrCount; $c++){
        $compattr2      .=  $result[$compPro][9][$c] . "\n";
    }
    $compattr2      .= '</td>';
}


// create the display
echo '<tr class="rowEven"><th>'  . COMPARE_QUANTITY     . '</th>' . $compQuantity     . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowOdd"> <th>'  . COMPARE_MODEL        . '</th>' . $compModel        . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowEven"><th>'  . COMPARE_WEIGHT       . '</th>' . $compWeight       . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowOdd"> <th>'  . COMPARE_MANUFACTURER . '</th>' . $compManufacturer . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowEven"><th>'  . COMPARE_DESC         . '</th>' . $compDescription  . '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="rowOdd"> <th>'  . COMPARE_OPTNAME      . '</th>' . $compattr1 . $compattr2 . '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: That is giving me a layout four cells wide rather than 2, with the content of $result[$compPro][8][$c] in the first 2 cells, and $result[$compPro][9][$c] content in the second 2. See https://jsfiddle.net/85wztu3z/3/ for a demo from the source code.

Comment: It's a little difficult to solve without seeing the whole code or databse, but please place the array that generates the example https://jsfiddle.net/uzmk61v7/2/